# Wigner-d matrices for higher (than 1/2) spins

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, group-representations

I’ve been reading

¨Halzen, F., and A. D. Martin. Quarks and Leptons. New York: Wiley Text Books, January 1984. ISBN: 9780471887416¨,

and I’d like some clarification of a concept, please: I’m looking at Problem 2.6, and the question asks us to show that the rotation matrices are represented by certain values, depending on the j-value used, for the equation: $d^{j}_{m’m}(\theta)=\langle{jm’}\lvert{e^{-i{\theta}{J_2}}}\lvert{jm}\rangle$. $J_2$ is represented as a rotation generator, $\theta$ is obviously the angle of rotation, $j$ represents the Eigenstate, and $m$-values are the different available states for each $j$-value. The question said that if $j={1 \over 2}$, we’d have:

$$j = {1 \over 2} 
\begin{cases}
d_{++} = d_{--} = \cos({1 \over 2}\theta) \\
d_{+-} = -d_{-+} = \sin({1 \over 2}\theta)
\end{cases}$$

, where $\pm$ designates $m = \pm {1 \over 2}$- values.

For $j=1$, I’m supposed to be able to find that:

$$j = 1 
\begin{cases}
d_{01} = -d_{10} = -d_{0-1} = d_{-10} = \sqrt{1 \over 2} sin(\theta) \\
d_{11} = d_{-1-1} = {1 \over 2} (1 + \cos\theta) \\
d_{-11} = d_{1-1} = {1 \over 2} (1 - \cos\theta) \\ 
d_{00} = \cos\theta
\end{cases}$$

Now, I’ve finished the first part, where we need to find the values for $j= {1 \over 2}$; I basically just used Euler’s Rule ($e^{ix} = \cos (x) + i\sin (x)$) to break down the exponential, and then considered odd and even-integer solutions.

I have several questions about the second part of the question:

1. How do I, in general, manipulate a higher-spin system, using a given operator? I feel like this has something to do with SU(3) or expanding SU(2) to SU(3), or perhaps I’m mistaken?
2. I looked at the solution to the first part in the book, and the authors used the Pauli Spin Matrices in order to solve it. Aren’t I doing the same thing with my own solution (as I described above), just without the explicit use of the Pauli Spin Matrices?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the question here is - why do you think SU(3) has anything to do with spin? I'm not sure how you introduced the spin representations, but if you constructed them from ladder operators, writing $J_2$ in terms of the ladder operators is probably the way to go.

Comment: Well in the very next section of the book, the authors introduce SU(2) and SU(3), so I suspected as much from the organizational scheme. and Yes, I constructed $J_2$ using the relation $J_{\pm} = J_{1} \pm iJ_{2}$.

Comment: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/lieg07.pdf

Comment: Disagree with the answer?

Answer (score 2):

- Your feeling looks very misguided. Whatever you do, stay away from SU(3) for rotations. The [rotation group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3)) and its Lie algebra are always linked to SO(3) ~ SU(2), to avoid formal forays into double covers and half angles. Read up on the [spin matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3)#A_note_on_Lie_algebra) for any representation of the very same group (any spin).
- There are, in fact, simple systematic generalizations for the simple Euler-like exponential of the Pauli matrices, for [spin 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation) and for [all representations of SU(2)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.3541v5.pdf), but this is distinctly egregious overkill, for your purpose. Wigner's [little d rotation matrices in the spherical representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix#Wigner_.28small.29_d-matrix) solves the problem simply and in full generality. The text you are referring to assumes the reader has taken a good QM course where all this is covered quite nicely.
- In any case, since it is safely late to do homework for one, recall [the expression for $J_2$ for spin one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3)#A_note_on_Lie_algebra),
  $$
   J_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
      \begin{bmatrix}
        0 &-i &0\\
        i &0  &-i\\
        0 &i  &0
      \end{bmatrix} \equiv iK,
  $$ 
  which you may [easily exponentiate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation#Exponential_map_from_%7F'"<code>UNIQ--postMath-00000007-QINU</code>"'%7F(3)_to_SO(3))
  $$
  e^{-i\theta J_2}=e^{\theta K}=  I + (\sin\theta) K  + (1-\cos\theta) K^2 ~,
  $$ 
  since you can confirm that $K^3=-K$, so $K^2$ behaves like *i* in combinatoric terms in the series for the exponential, when multiplied by *K*. 
  Now, since 
  $$
  K^2=  \begin{bmatrix}
        -1/2 &0 &0\\
        0 &-1  &0\\
        0 &0  &-1/2
      \end{bmatrix} ,
  $$
  the net rotation in the exponential is just 
  $$
  e^{-i\theta J_2}= \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{1+\cos\theta}{2} &-\sin\theta /\sqrt{2} & \frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}\\
        \sin\theta /\sqrt{2} &\cos \theta  &-\sin\theta /\sqrt{2}\\
         \frac{1-\cos\theta}{2} &\sin\theta /\sqrt{2}  &\frac{1+\cos\theta}{2}
      \end{bmatrix} .
  $$
  You are done. From this, you simply read off the spherical basis matrix elements you have for the destination Wigner *d*-matrix stated.